# What exactly is the meaning of False-positive operation in sonar?

Tags: testing, sonarqube

When I encounter a violation in Sonar (in violation drilldown tab), in the source code view Sonar has some action like comment, assign, etc, one of those is False-positive, I want to know what exactly is the meaning of this operation, and when should I use it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As any automatic tool, Sonar - and the rule engines it relies on (Findbugs/PMD/Checkstyle/...), can make "mistakes" while raising a violation: only a human can detect this, and you have the ability to flag this "mistake" as a false-positive to be sure that you won't spend time on it again.

Obviously, this feature must not be used to mute real violations. What's more, each time you flag a violation as false-positive, a good habit is to write a meaningful comment (and also report the issue on the user mailing list of the corresponding tool).

Answer (score 2):

False-positive is then the software tells you there is a violation but you know better (like there is a reason, better than laziness, why the statement is poorly written) and this way you can mark the encounter as "Done The Right Way".

However, this functionality is sometimes used to get "clean" report for the manager. It's the worst that could happen.

Generally speaking - you should not use it.

Comment: I agree with you but ... Well, in some cases you need to use it. For instance if you want to get a correct report of valid violations.  Of course the best way to handle it is to refactor your code.

Comment: @ppapapetrou If you know there are some mild violations that won't get repaired (ever), then there is always option to define custom set of rules. However, this requires recognition and additional work from the maintainer.

Comment: ohai, Downvoter. Thank you for your meaningful update. Could you please provide some feedback?